# bad weak pointer when base and derived class both inherit from boost::enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, multiple-inheritance, enable-shared-from-this

I have a base class which derives from boost::enable_shared_from_this, and then another class which derives from both the base class and boost::enable_shared_from_this:

```
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using namespace boost;

class A : public enable_shared_from_this<A> { };

class B : public A , public enable_shared_from_this<B> {
public:
    using enable_shared_from_this<B>::shared_from_this;
};

int main() {
shared_ptr<B> b = shared_ptr<B>(new B());
shared_ptr<B> b_ = b->shared_from_this();

return 0;
}
```

This compiles but at runtime it gives

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_weak_ptr> >'
  what():  tr1::bad_weak_ptr
Aborted
```

What is causing this, and is there some way around it?

EDIT:

What if I need something like this:

```
class A : public enable_shared_from_this<A> { };
class B : public enable_shared_from_this<B> { };    

class C : public A, public B, public enable_shared_from_this<C> {
public:
    using enable_shared_from_this<C>::shared_from_this;
};
```

such that A and B both need shared_from_this on their own (and one can't inherit it from the other), and C needs A, B, and shared_from_this?

Comment: I know that b_ would be the same as b and in this case I could just use b. But this is just a demonstration; other cases in which I actually need to use shared_from_this will cause the same error.

Comment: My solution in that case would involve virtual inheritance. I suspect boost may already have a class for this, perhaps a non-templated version of `enable_shared_from_this`. But if it didn't, I'd create my own and virtually inherit from it anywhere I needed the functionality. You'd have to use `dynamic_pointer_cast` instead of `static_pointer_cast` of course. But it'd work.

Comment: Yeah - I can't see an obviously clean way to make this work.  It's close to diamond inheritance, and probably suggests that a rethink of the design is in order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I would solve your problem:

```
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using namespace boost;

class virt_enable_shared_from_this :
   public enable_shared_from_this<virt_enable_shared_from_this>
{
 public:
   virtual ~virt_enable_shared_from_this() {}
};

template <class T>
class my_enable_shared_from_this : virtual public virt_enable_shared_from_this
{
 public:
   shared_ptr<T> shared_from_this() {
      return dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(virt_enable_shared_from_this::shared_from_this());
   }
};

class A : public my_enable_shared_from_this<A> { };

class B : public my_enable_shared_from_this<B> { };

class C : public A, public B, public my_enable_shared_from_this<C> {
 public:
   using my_enable_shared_from_this<C>::shared_from_this;
};

int main() {
   shared_ptr<C> c = shared_ptr<C>(new C());
   shared_ptr<C> c_ = c->shared_from_this();

   return 0;
}
```

This is painful and at least a bit ugly. But it works reasonably well, after a fashion. I think [Fraser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424459/fraser)'s idea of re-thinking your design is likely the better option.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `virt_enable_shared_from_this` without it inheriting `virtual`ly from `enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: `enable_shared_from_this` is a template. So everybody virtually inheriting from a template isn't going to help the situation because each of those template instances is different. `virt_enable_shared_from_this` is to give a common base class for everybody to virtually inherit from.

Comment: I think you could replace `dynamic_pointer_cast` with `static_pointer_cast` it is safe here...and faster

Comment: @kassak: Maybe. I don't want to risk it. virtual base classes can float around inside the class layout in interesting ways.

Answer (score 11):

You shouldn't inherit from `enable_shared_from_this` more than once in a given inheritance chain.

In this case, you can leave the base class `A` inheriting from `enable_shared_from_this`, and have the derived class `B` return a `shared_ptr<A>` and then [`static_pointer_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#static_pointer_cast) it to `shared_ptr<B>`.

Or as Omnifarious pointed out, you could have a function in `B` which does this for you.  Although, rather than overloading `shared_from_this()` I would favour explicitly-named functions to minimise surprises for clients of the class:

```
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using boost::shared_ptr;

class A : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<A> { };

class B : public A {
public:
    using enable_shared_from_this<A>::shared_from_this;
    shared_ptr<B> shared_B_from_this() {
        return boost::static_pointer_cast<B>(shared_from_this());
    }
    shared_ptr<B const> shared_B_from_this() const {
        return boost::static_pointer_cast<B const>(shared_from_this());
    }
};

int main() {
    shared_ptr<B> b = shared_ptr<B>(new B);
    shared_ptr<B> b1 = boost::static_pointer_cast<B>(b->shared_from_this());
    shared_ptr<B> b2 = b->shared_B_from_this();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or even better, overload shared_from_this in the derived class to do the cast for you.

Comment: I was afraid the answer was going to be something like that. Here's a situation that's a little closer to what I actually have:
`class A : public enable_shared_from_this<A> { };
class B : public enable_shared_from_this<B> { };    

class C : public A, public B, public enable_shared_from_this<C> {
public:
    using enable_shared_from_this<C>::shared_from_this;
};`
so you can see A cannot get shared_from_this through inheritance from B (or vis-versa). So how can use use shared_from_this in all of A, B, and C?

Comment: gah the comment system removes new lines, which makes it almost unreadable.. I'll edit my original question as well.