# std::bad_weak_ptr after inheriting from class that inherits from std::enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, c++20, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

I have the following piece of code:

```cpp
#include <memory>

class A: public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {};

struct B: public A, public std::enable_shared_from_this<B> {
    std::shared_ptr<B> get() {        
        return enable_shared_from_this<B>::shared_from_this();
    }
};

int main(){
    auto b = std::make_shared<B>();
    auto p = b->get();
}
```

Compiling with both clang (15.0.0) and gcc (12.2), and running it leads to a `std::bad_weak_ptr` exception. I'm curious to understand why that is so. Thanks.

```
-std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -fsanitize=address
```

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
  what():  bad_weak_ptr
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address (pc 0x7f0e60632941 bp 0x7f0e607fd780 sp 0x7ffdb646eee0 T0)
==1==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==1==Hint: this fault was caused by a dereference of a high value address (see register values below).  Disassemble the provided pc to learn which register was used.
    #0 0x7f0e60632941 in abort (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x22941)
    #1 0x7f0e60a1ba48  (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6+0xa9a48)
    #2 0x7f0e60a27079  (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6+0xb5079)
    #3 0x7f0e60a270e4 in std::terminate() (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6+0xb50e4)
    #4 0x7f0e60a27336 in __cxa_throw (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6+0xb5336)
    #5 0x4011a3 in std::__throw_bad_weak_ptr() /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:96
    #6 0x4011a3 in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count(std::__weak_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> const&) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1245
    #7 0x4011a3 in std::__shared_ptr<B, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<B, void>(std::__weak_ptr<B, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> const&) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1548
    #8 0x4011a3 in std::shared_ptr<B>::shared_ptr<B, void>(std::weak_ptr<B> const&) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:381
    #9 0x4011a3 in std::enable_shared_from_this<B>::shared_from_this() /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:935
    #10 0x4011a3 in B::get() /app/example.cpp:7
    #11 0x4011a3 in main /app/example.cpp:13
    #12 0x7f0e60634082 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
    #13 0x4016cd in _start (/app/output.s+0x4016cd)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x22941) in abort
==1==ABORTING
```

Comment: Not sure it's a duplicate, but does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549722/double-inheritance-of-enable-shared-from-this

Comment: No reason to use multiple inheritance for that. `B` is convertible to `A` so `A` is convertible to `B` and you're in a situation where you know you're getting an instance of `B` in `get` so IMHO `std::static_pointer_cast` is a more effective approach.

Answer (score 2):

`enable_shared_from_this` is made to work by various `shared_ptr` constructors - but only if it's an unambiguous and accessible base class of the class whose pointer is passed to `shared_ptr` constructor. In your example, `enable_shared_from_this` base is ambiguous.

> **[util.smartptr.shared.const]/1** In the constructor definitions below, enables `shared_from_this` with `p`, for a pointer `p` of type `Y*`, means that if `Y` has an **unambiguous and accessible** base class that is a specialization of `enable_shared_from_this` (20.11.6), then `remove_cv_t<Y>*` shall be implicitly convertible to `T*` and the constructor evaluates the statement:
>
> ```
> if (p != nullptr && p->weak_this.expired())
>   p->weak_this = shared_ptr<remove_cv_t<Y>>(*this, const_cast<remove_cv_t<Y>*>(p));
> ```

Emphasis mine.