# Use of enable_shared_from_this with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, multiple-inheritance, enable-shared-from-this

BI am using `enable_shared_from_this` in my code, and I am not sure if its usage is correct. This is the code:

```
class A: public std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
public:
    void foo1()
    {
        auto ptr = shared_from_this(); 
    }
};

class B:public std::enable_shared_from_this<B>
{
public:
    void foo2()
    {
        auto ptr = shared_from_this(); 
    }
};

class C:public std::enable_shared_from_this<C>
{
public:
    void foo3()
    {
        auto ptr = shared_from_this(); 
    }
};

class D: public A, public B, public C
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        auto ptr = A::shared_from_this(); 
    }
};
```

Are these usage of `make_shared_from_this()` correct, assuming that they are always being called through `shared_ptr` of D?

Comment: I don't think `foo2` or `foo3` would compile...

Comment: yep that doesn't make sense, only class A inherits enable_shared_from_this<>

Comment: I think you should take a look at what enable_shared_from_this does. See the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712279/what-is-the-usefulness-of-enable-shared-from-this)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939190/boost-shared-from-this-and-multiple-inheritance

Comment: I apologize for the syntactical mistakes. Updated the code.

Comment: yep that's better :-)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Indeed you are doing it wrong. If you have simple inheritance, just inherit from `enable_shared_from this` in the base class, and derived class get it for free. (of course you'll need to downcast the result)

If you have multiple inheritance (like it seems), you must use the trick described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549722/double-inheritance-of-enable-shared-from-this) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939190/boost-shared-from-this-and-multiple-inheritance) :

```
/* Trick to allow multiple inheritance of objects
 * inheriting shared_from_this.
 * cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12793989/587407
 */

/* First a common base class
 * of course, one should always virtually inherit from it.
 */
class MultipleInheritableEnableSharedFromThis
: public std::enable_shared_from_this<MultipleInheritableEnableSharedFromThis> {
public:
  virtual ~MultipleInheritableEnableSharedFromThis()
  {}
};

template <class T>
class inheritable_enable_shared_from_this
: virtual public MultipleInheritableEnableSharedFromThis {
public:
  std::shared_ptr<T> shared_from_this() {
    return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(
        MultipleInheritableEnableSharedFromThis::shared_from_this()
    );
  }
  /* Utility method to easily downcast.
   * Useful when a child doesn't inherit directly from enable_shared_from_this
   * but wants to use the feature.
   */
  template <class Down>
  std::shared_ptr<Down> downcasted_shared_from_this() {
    return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Down>(
       MultipleInheritableEnableSharedFromThis::shared_from_this()
    );
  }
};
```

Then your code becomes :

```
class A: public inheritable_enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
public:
    void foo1()
    {
        auto ptr = shared_from_this(); 
    }
};

class B: public inheritable_enable_shared_from_this<B>
{
public:
    void foo2()
    {
        auto ptr = shared_from_this(); 
    }
};

class C: public inheritable_enable_shared_from_this<C>
{
public:
    void foo3()
    {
        auto ptr = shared_from_this(); 
    }
};

class D: public A, public B, public C
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        auto ptr = A::downcasted_shared_from_this<D>(); 
    }
};
```

Comment: Note: derived classes will only be able to use the inherited enable_shared_from_this if it is public, i.e.: `class BaseClass: public enable_shared_from_this<BaseClass>`.

Comment: @Offirmo Is there any possible solution in case I am unable to modify (inherit from inheritable_enable_shared_from_this) the base classes (A, B, C)?