# How can I implement a variadic class template with a specialization for only a certain number of parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, crtp

I've written what I would hoped to be a general purpose CRTP class that allows my own classes to easily extend a class that implements a `shared_from_this` function (presumably returning a shared pointer equivalent to this), giving direct access to the shared pointer for the derived class instead of the base, as follows:

```
template<class Self, class Super>
class inherit_shared_from_this : public Super {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<const Self> shared_from_this() const {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<const Self>(Super::shared_from_this());
    }
    std::shared_ptr<Self> shared_from_this() {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<Self>(Super::shared_from_this());
    }
};
```

This works quite well for single inheritance trees, but I was wanting to extend it to be able to inherit from more than one class that implements `shared_from_this`.   When I do so, however, I get an error 'shared_from_this' is ambiguous, because the compiler can't tell which exact class I am meaning to inherit the `shared_from_this` function.  In fact, it does not matter which one.

What I wanted to do is define a class as follows:

```
class Foo : public inherit_shared_from_this<Foo, A, B, C> {
...
};
```

Where all of A, B, C, and D implement a `shared_from_this` function, and this class will publicly inherit from each of the classes other than the first, and implement exactly two `shared_from_this` methods, for both const and non-const versions, to return the applicable shared_pointer version of `this` (in this case, `std::shared_ptr<Foo>`).

The first thing I tried to do was adding a variadic definition for the class as follows:

```
template<class Self, class Super, typename... Args>
class inherit_shared_from_this : public Super, public inherit_shared_from_this<Self, Args...> {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<const Self> shared_from_this() const {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<const Self>(Super::shared_from_this());
    }
    std::shared_ptr<Self> shared_from_this() {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<Self>(Super::shared_from_this());
    }
};
```

That did not work, however... it objected that the two definitions of `inherit_shared_from_this` had different numbers of parameters.

Any ideas on how I can do what I am trying to accomplish, or is it just not possible?

EDIT:

A clarification on why `std::shared_from_this` is not usable as-is:

If I simply inherit directly from the class that inherited `std::enable_shared_from_this` in a derived class that also inherits from something that inherited from `std::enable_shared_from_this`, then it returns the wrong pointer type. If I use multiple inheritance and also inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this` in a derived class whose base had extended `std::enable_shared_from_this`, then calling `shared_from_this()` in the derived class is ambiguous.  Therefore a class that can inherit from such classes is required if access to the derived pointer is wanted.

EDIT:
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082785/use-of-enable-shared-from-this-with-multiple-inheritance) differs from mine in that I am wanting to avoid adding virtual inheritance into things unless it is explicitly asked for.  Since std::enable_shared_from_this itself does not have a virtual destructor in the first place, it seems improper to add that cost to what I am trying to design as a general purpose class whose purpose is to be just as reusable.

Comment: Why are you not using [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)?

Comment: I do use it.  The  problem is with descendant classes...  I had assumed that this was obvious, and so did not mention it previously.  I've updated the text of the problem.

Comment: I think I begin to understand what your issue is. The problem with the different numbers of parameters can be solved by specialisation: the version with the smaller number of parameters can be specialised version. Even better, the variadic version alone should suffice, as an empty pack is allowed.

Comment: why does your variadic `inherit_shared_from_this<Self,Super,Args...>` inherit from `inherit_shared_from_this<Self,Args...>`?

Comment: Well, it's already inherited directly from Super, so it doesn't need that anymore... so it needs to inherit publicly from the next  Super in the Args list

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [Use of enable_shared_from_this with multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082785/use-of-enable-shared-from-this-with-multiple-inheritance)? Also for single inheritance, you don't need anything else than `std::enable_shared_from_this`, don't you?

Comment: For single inheritance, I can use std::enable_shared_from_this for each of my base types, and then my initial implementation of inherit_shared_from_this for any derived types.   That works just fine for that case.  I was wanting to extend it, however, to accomodate multiple inheritance.

Comment: If a derived class inherits two different base classes that inherit specializations of `std::enable_shared_from_this`, I think you have bigger problems.  Doesn't the compiler complain when you try to create a `shared_ptr` to such a type?

Comment: Yes... that's why I was wanting to use a CRTP to implement its own `shared_from_this` to override the other base class's `shared_from_this` methods.

Comment: Oh, hmm. I guess that doesn't actually cause compile errors like I expected, at least with the g++ library.  Instead, `shared_from_this` simply fails: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1770d06dcc62889e

Comment: Aha, the behavior of my little program is correct. Per the Standard, the functions such as `make_shared` or `shared_ptr` constructors which enable `shared_from_this` only work if the type has an **unambiguous** and accessible base class which is a specialization of `enable_shared_from_this`. Otherwise, just nothing happens.