# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr' what(): bad_weak_ptr?

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-ptr, weak-ptr, enable-shared-from-this

I'm learning smart pointers and `shared_from_this`.  In Class Inheritance Relations, it will be very hard to understand.

I have two base classes `CA` and `CB`, they are derived from `enable_shared_from_this`, and the child class `CC` derives from both `CA` and `CB`.
I want to take out of the three classes shared pointer from the class self, so I write the `sharedCAfromThis`, `sharedCBfromThis` and `sharedCCfromthis`.

```
class CA  : private enable_shared_from_this<CA> {
public:
    shared_ptr<CA> sharedCAfromThis() { return shared_from_this();  }
    virtual ~CA() {};
    void print() {
        cout << "CA" << endl;
    }
};

class CB : private enable_shared_from_this<CB> {
public:
    shared_ptr<CB> sharedCBfromThis() { return shared_from_this();  }
    virtual ~CB() {};
    void print() {
        cout << "CB" << endl;
    }
};

class CC : public CA, CB {
public:
    shared_ptr<CC> sharedCCfromThis() { return dynamic_pointer_cast<CC>(sharedCAfromThis());  }
    virtual ~CC() {};
    void print() {
        cout << "CC" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<CC> cc_ptr = make_shared<CC>();
    cc_ptr->sharedCAfromThis()->print();
    //shared_ptr<C> c_ptr = make_shared<C>();
    //c_ptr->get_shared_b()->printb();
    while (1);
}
```

but I am wrong the problems are:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
  what():  bad_weak_ptr
```

Why am I getting this error message?

hi, yes, thank you very much, I change the private to public, but the problem still exists. my gcc version is 8.0; I change the code as below.

```
class CA  : public enable_shared_from_this<CA> {
public:
    shared_ptr<CA> sharedCAfromThis() { return shared_from_this();  }
    virtual ~CA() {};
    void print() {
        cout << "CA" << endl;
    }
};

class CB : public enable_shared_from_this<CB> {
public:
    shared_ptr<CB> sharedCBfromThis() { return shared_from_this();  }
    virtual ~CB() {};
    void print() {
        cout << "CB" << endl;
    }
};

class CC : public CA, CB, enable_shared_from_this<CC> {
public:
    shared_ptr<CC> sharedCCfromThis() { return dynamic_pointer_cast<CC>(sharedCAfromThis());  }
    virtual ~CC() {};
    void print() {
        cout << "CC" << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: What is unclear in [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) *ie. public inheritance is mandatory* ?

Comment: yes public inheritance is mandatory

Comment: @rafix07 The unclear part is that is only required since C++17 according to this reference, and question didn't specify standard version.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen With no language version explicitly specified, I think it's quite reasonable to assume *current latest version* - which, at the moment, is C++17.

Comment: I'm not sure if that smart pointer implementation catches this through some magic, but I'm afraid you're still going to shoot yourself in the foot. Both the `CA` and `CB` subobject have an according `shared_from_this<>` subobject. This may result in two completely independent smart pointers trying to manage the lifetime of the same object, which will lead to desaster. Try to retrieve both smart pointers from an instance, their destruction will then possibly cause double destruction of the instance.

Comment: May be a dup of:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082785/use-of-enable-shared-from-this-with-multiple-inheritance

Comment: It's probably a language defect. You should submit to the compiler writers who will submit to the C++ std committee.

Answer (score 5):

You should inherit publicly from `enable_shared_from_this`.  Per [[util.smartptr.shared.const]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/util.smartptr.shared.const#1):

> In the constructor definitions below, enables `shared_­from_­this`
>   with `p`, for a pointer `p` of type `Y*`, means that if `Y` has **an
>   unambiguous and accessible base class** that is a specialization of
>   `enable_­shared_­from_­this`, then `remove_­cv_­t<Y>*` shall be
>   implicitly convertible to `T*` and the constructor evaluates the
>   statement:
>
> ```
> if (p != nullptr && p->weak_this.expired())
>   p->weak_this = shared_ptr<remove_cv_t<Y>>(*this, const_cast<remove_cv_t<Y>*>(p));
> ```
>
> The assignment to the `weak_­this` member is not atomic and conflicts
>   with any potentially concurrent access to the same object
>   ([intro.multithread]).

If you use private inheritance, the base class is not accessible anymore.

Comment: thank you, but when I change private to public, the problem still exists

Comment: @justin.shen That's another problem ...  You can ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that you have a duplicate. You need to make sure there is only one `enable_shared_from_this`.

To do that with classes, you can virtually derive the class:

```
class A : virtual public enable_shared_from_this<A> ...
class B : virtual public enable_shared_from_this<B> ...

class C : public A, public B ...
```

Now you have a single instance of the `enable_shared_from_this<>` and this should work as expected. Otherwise, it may use the version from B which is likely a `nullptr`, hence the error.