# Can I derive indirectly form std::enable_shared_from_this()?

Tags: c++, oop

In the folowing example:

```
class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
   
};

class B : public A {
    
};
```

can I use `shared_from_this()` in class `B` without any problems? I mean, is it necessary to derive directly from `std::enable_shared_from_this`, or can I derive indirecly by the use of a Base class which derives from it like in the above example?

I want to know if this logic works.

I am thinking that it might not work because `std::enable_shared_from_this` is sharing a pointer of object `A` not of object `B`. It might compile, but when run it can create undisered outputs.

Comment: `B` inherits all of `A`, including any base classes of `A`.

Comment: why would it not work?

Comment: I am thinking that it might not work because std::enable_shared_from_this is sharing a pointer of object A not of object B. It might compile, but when run it can create undisered outputs.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem deriving from a class which inherits from `std::enable_shared_from_this`. For example this code will work:

```
#include <memory>

class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
public:   
    void bar()
    {
        auto a = shared_from_this();
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void foo()
    {
        auto a = shared_from_this();
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto b = std::make_shared<B>();
    b->foo();
    b->bar();
}
```

Conversely deriving from `std::enable_shared_from_this` multiple times can lead to issues:

```
#include <memory>

class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
public:   
    void bar()
    {
        auto a = shared_from_this();
    }
};

class B : public A, public std::enable_shared_from_this<B> {
public:
    void foo()
    {
        auto a = std::enable_shared_from_this<B>::shared_from_this();
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto b = std::make_shared<B>();
    b->foo();
    b->bar();
}
```

Now `shared_from_this` is ambiguous in `B` so we have to explicitly qualify it when we use it but worse it'll stop working properly: [bad weak pointer when base and derived class both inherit from boost::enable_shared_from_this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790859/bad-weak-pointer-when-base-and-derived-class-both-inherit-from-boostenable-sha)

Note that you should add a virtual destructor to `A` to avoid potential pitfalls when destructing objects (though `shared_ptr`, when used correctly, does workaround this issue)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `B` publicly inherits everything from `A`, including its base classes.

That means that you can use `shared_from_this()` just as you would for an `A` (i.e. only on an instance that is owned by a shared pointer).

Note that we'll always get a pointer to `A`, not to the more derived class `B`.  If we need to get a `std::shared_ptr<B>`, we'll need to down-cast using `std::dynamic_pointer_cast()`, <s>or to also derive from `std::enable_shared_from_this<B>`</s>.

[Don't try to derive from multiple different `enable_shared_from_this` bases](/a/12791172/4850040); instead, if we need B to return pointer-to-B, shadow the function:

```
    shared_ptr<B> B::shared_from_this() {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<B>(A::shared_from_this());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "it works, but not necessarily how you wanted it to".

When you implement class `A` inheriting from `std::enable_shared_from_this<A>`
you get a `shared_from_this` method that returns a  `std::shared_ptr<A>`. That does not change when you implement class `B` inheriting from `A`. That is, calling `shared_from_this` from a `shared_ptr<B>` will give you a `shared_ptr<A>` object (when maybe you hoped for a `shared_ptr<B>`). It will still do the right thing regarding the reference counting (thus, it does work), and it will behave just like using an `A` pointer to point to a `B` object.

We can confirm this with the code below

```cpp
class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
public:
    std::string getName() const { return "A"; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    std::string getName() const { return "B"; }
    int getAge() const { return 20; }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    auto a = std::make_shared<A>();
    auto a2 = a->shared_from_this();
    auto b = std::make_shared<B>();
    auto b2 = b->shared_from_this();

    std::cout << "a->getName():  " << a->getName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a2->getName(): " << a2->getName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b->getName():  " << b->getName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b2->getName(): " << b2->getName() << std::endl;
    // b2->getAge();  // compile error

    std::cout << "a use_count: " << a.use_count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b use_count: " << a.use_count() << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

This will print

```
a->getName():  A
a2->getName(): A
b->getName():  B
b2->getName(): A
a use_count: 2
b use_count: 2
```

As we can see, the call to `b2->getName()` returned `"A"` and not `"B"`, since the `b2` variable type is `shared_ptr<A>`. That can be easily fixed by making `getName` in class `A` a virtual method (as it probably should). Also, note that a call to `b2->getAge()` won't compile because `getAge` is not part of class `A`.